# Cloned SSD won't boot Windows 8, shows "Your PC/Device needs to be repaired"

Tags: windows, ssd, bsod, clone, disk-cloning

A friend of mine asked me to help him migrate his original HDD to an SSD (Crucial MX500 480GB) he bought. He's using a 27" HP Envy Recline Touchsmart All-in-one PC.

So I went and used the same software I've been using for years (EaseUS Todo Backup Free 11.5), only this time it won't boot. It gives me a BSOD and shuts down after a few seconds. I installed the source HDD and target SSD in a Lenovo M73p tower case because my USB HDD docking station died. Could this have anything to do with it?

The BIOS in the HP Envy has Secure boot enabled and Legacy boot disabled. The SSD is the only drive installed and boot order is correct.

Windows startup repair doesn't do anything.

I tried (didn't help):

- bootrec /scanos
- bootrec /rebuildbcd
- bootrec /fixmbr
- bootrec /fixboot

I haven't tried rebuilding the EFI partition yet...

[image: Disk Manager]

[image: Disk Part]

[image: BSOD]

Comment: The boot error code is `0xc0000225`, which means "Windows cannot find the System Files used for booting". Your clone doesn't seem to have been cloned correctly. Maybe you should try another software, example [AOMEI](https://www.ubackup.com/help/disk-clone.html).

Comment: @harrymc I tried Acronis True Image for Crucial (target SSD is Crucial MX500) and the end result is the same - can't boot. Free version of AOMEI only lets you clone MBR disks, not GPT.

Comment: Does the disk perhaps use Bitlocker?

Comment: @harrymc not that I'm aware of. It has OEM Windows installed from the factory and everything else that goes with it (recovery partition etc).

Comment: If your disk is GPT, there was no point in running `bootrec /fixmbr`. It's abnormal for an advanced cloning software to fail, even if there are size differences (please give more information about the disks). I note that EaseUS Todo Backup is currently at version 13.5, so you might try the newer version.

Comment: I also tried EaseUS Todo Backup version 12 with same result. Versions 13+ won't let you clone the disk and wants you to 'upgrade' to Home version which is payable. I don't want to give them $30 and risk getting the same result which is probable. Windows 8 has been around for years, so even version 11.5 should be able to deal with it. I think it has to do with OEM installation and the way HP has the drive partitioned. Not sure, just a hunch.

The source hard drive is Seagate SSHD 1000GB 2.5", target drive is Crucial MX500 500GB SSD.

Comment: Another suggestion: Is SecureBoot enabled, perhaps? This might cause an error of that kind. Oh, and, btw, if you want to clone a disk properly, try dd, it has never caused me a problem, even when cloning windows boot drives.

Comment: Yes, as stated in the post, Secure boot is enabled. It has been from the start so I don't see why that would be a problem? I did try disabling it only to get a different error (don't remember which, possibly missing winload.efi but not sure).

Do you mean this? https://serverspace.io/support/help/dd-utility-for-windows-backup/

Comment: Cloning to a half-sized disk is problematic and sometimes impossible. You should reduce the disk space used by Windows to the minimum, perhaps disable the pagefile, defragment the partition so used data moves upwards, then clone. Success is not guaranteed if the used space in the Windows partition is too much.

Comment: Interesting point. Since SSDs used to be much more expensive, I regularly did just that: clone a 500GB HDD to a 240GB SSD for example. I don't remember ever having problems with that on the account of size mismatch. However, you might have a point in this case because the used space on the source drive is almost as big as the entire SSD.

I'll try to manually rebuild the EFI partition. If that doesn't work, I'll give Macrium Reflect a try. I noticed people who had problems with EaseUS, had better luck with Macrium.

Comment: I clone using Macrium Reflect Free,  no failures so far in years.

Comment: OK, there seems to be a problem with the original hard drive as well... I can't boot from it for some reason.

Comment: I disabled 'Secure boot' in BIOS and enabled AHCI and it booted successfully. Only took about 5 minutes... I'll go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went and got EaseUS Todo Backup Home and tried System Clone (something which the free version doesn't allow you to do). Surprisingly it worked so this question can be closed.

I don't understand the exact difference between a Disk clone and a System clone because Disk clone works just fine with Windows 7 or stock (non-OEM) Windows 8 installations.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't work, if the PC that contains the drive you're trying to clone doesn't work. System Clone function does not work when both drives (source and target) are moved to a different system.